# External USB graphic card display adapter to VGA for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: usb, video-adapters, ubuntu, vga

What external USB graphic card display adapter to VGA is working with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

I would like to use one similar to this one: JUA210 USB 2.0 VGA Display Adapter (https://en.j5create.com/products/jua210?variant=10607890692). Any recommendation or does this one even run on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: See here some info about it https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169533/usb-to-vga-on-linux